# Docker build hangs with a run

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to build a docker image from a Dockerfile. The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3
RUN ls -alF
RUN python main.py
```

The ls command is executed, but once it finishes the process hangs and does not continue with the execution. If I enter the base docker image and execute the commands by hand everything works. Why does it happen?

EDIT

The problem happens in the first line in the Dockerfile of RUN type. The command is correclty executed and the result appears in the screen, but after that the build hangs and does not continue. It happens if the line is "RUN ls", "RUN python main.py", "RUN pip install xxxx" or whetever, so the problem is the RUN command. If I use a COPY or ADD command, the behaviour is correct. With other base images such as simple ubuntu the problem persists.

Comment: What does `main.py` do?

Comment: It is a simple python program that only prints a sentence. But it does not matter, since the execution hangs before reaching that line of the dockerfile.

Comment: This wasn't cleat from your question, please add as much context as possible.

Comment: The problem happens in the first line in the Dockerfile of RUN type. The command is correclty executed and the result appears in the screen, but after that the build hangs and does not continue. It happens if the line is "RUN ls", "RUN python main.py", "RUN pip install xxxx" or whetever, so the problem is the RUN command. If I use a COPY or ADD command, the behaviour is correct.

Comment: I get `can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when building this. Where is `main.py` coming from?

Comment: I deleted a COPY command in the Dockerfile that copys the file in order to simplify the question since this operations is working correclty. The problem happens in the first RUN command it finds.

Comment: I had some issue int he past with docker hanging, I restart the service and it would work again.

Comment: It solved the problem. Thanks!!